# Ruby rest client array of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm updating my rest-client gem from 1.8 to 2.0.

On 1.8 it sends an array of params on a get request as `my-url?ids=1,2,3,4`.
But on 2.0 it uses duplicated keys like `my-url?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`. For reasons beyond the context of this question, our back end does NOT support the new multiple keys syntax (ok, it supports it, but we'll have to make a big refactor). So I'd like to know if there's a way to use the 2.0 client version and keep sending get array requests with only one key and separated by comma as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `rest-client` docs https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#query-parameters it seems your only option would be to serialize the parameters yourself and add them to the URL as the query string.

> If you don't like this behavior and want more control, just serialize params yourself (e.g. with URI.encode_www_form) and add the query string to the URL directly for GET parameters or pass the payload as a string for POST requests.

If you provide some sample code on how you're using the gem, we could help out a bit better with sample answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok yeah [Leo Correa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261399/leo-correa) was right, so what I had to do is replace my old code

```
params = {
    partner_key: @partner,
    resources: ["front_end_config", "gui_settings"]
}
@response = JSON.parse( RestClient.get( "#{api_base_uri}/partner_config.json", params: params.merge({multipart:true}) ) )
```

with this new one, serializing and encoding by myself...

```
params = {
    partner_key: @partner,
    resources: '["front_end_config", "gui_settings"]'
}
params = URI.encode_www_form(params.merge({multipart:true}))
@response = JSON.parse( RestClient.get( "#{api_base_uri}/partner_config.json?#{params}" ) )
```

It's ugly as hell, but it worked for me. If there's some other idea on how to make it better, I'd appreciate.